# How would you translate "more" for use as an interface button?

Tags: word-choice, word-requests

I'm working on an interface that includes several tabs to organize information about a topic. In the English version, the last tab is labeled "More", and it shows additional details about the topic.

What would be the most appropriate Japanese translation to use for this button?

**Note:** The button is restricted to a small space so I am looking for a short word, ideally around 5 or less characters.

[image]

Comment: And actually I think "more" is the easier one. UI like "show less" is the real headache.

Answer (score 17):

Wikipedia has the shortest translation of 'more' button: 他

> [image: sidebar comparison of 'more' and '他' on Wikipedia]
>
> `文A 他 189` on [ja.wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E) (left) and `文A 189 more` on [en.wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_language) (right)

Firefox has a different translation of 'more' menu button: その他

> [image: application menu of 'more' and 'その他' in Firefox]
>
> `その他 >` in Firefox with Japanese language pack (left) and `More >` in Firefox with English language pack (right)

Given the context, such as menu item count or other associated words, the translation of 'more' can just be '他'. Without the context, the translation of 'more' can just be 'その他'.

The word choice depends on the design and intention.

Comment: I like this answer a lot. Also perhaps「その他」could work well here.　Like [shown here](http://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/a/aitatena/20140921/20140921135952.jpg) 

The google image search for [その他　ボタン] vs [他　ボタン] has fewer results, but most of the top results for the latter have pictures of clothing buttons while the first is mostly software buttons. Not saying that either is better than the other though and I don't have a lot of time spent on the Japanese internet.

Comment: That depends: Wikipedia likely wanted to emphasize the article has been localized to how many languages, so `他 N-items` works well. A search engine or an app store tend to have varying number of items or volatile count, so `その他` works well. P.S.: May be I should add one more example?

Comment: @samuraiseoul - I didn't want to overcomplicate my question, but maybe it would help if I include a screenshot. How do you think this looks? Would 「その他」 work better? https://i.imgur.com/hjenrSw.png

Comment: Um, not sure if the comment was intended to me or the other mentioned user... Regarding the screenshot by OP: yes, I think `その他` would work better because the context is not apparent in the shown app.

Comment: I concur with @clearkimura. You should update your question to include the screenshot as well for future viewers.

Answer (score 16):

Possible options are:

- 詳細 (literally "detail")
- その他 (literally "others")
- もっと見る / さらに見る (literally "see more")
- もっと読む / さらに読む (literally "read more")

もっと/さらに + 見る/読む may be the most literal, and it is suitable as the caption of the button in ["manual infinite scroll" UI](https://connekthq.com/plugins/ajax-load-more/). But as the caption of the rightmost tab, I feel 詳細 or その他 would look more natural.

**EDIT:** Judging from the screenshot, I would say 詳細 may be the best option. Other tab names ("info = 情報", "stats = ステータス") are already somewhat vague, and people may wonder "What is 'others' which is *not* 'info'?". 詳細 clearly indicates it contains relatively unimportant information. (But if the "more" tab contains misc actionable buttons/commands, その他 may be better.)

Comment: Youtube uses `もっと読み込む` for it's infinite-scroll more button. A bit too long for OP's wishes though.